# R: customised function for VIF

Tags: r, regression, correlation, r-car

I am trying to write a loop to calculate Variance Inflation Factor. I understand there are functions and packages that can do this for me but I need some sort of customisation.

A sample data

```
  library(MASS)
  library(clusterGeneration)

  set.seed(2)
  num.vars <- 30
  num.obs<-200
  cov.mat<- genPositiveDefMat(num.vars,covMethod="unifcorrmat")$Sigma
  rand.vars<- mvrnorm(num.obs,rep(0,num.vars),Sigma=cov.mat)

  cov.mat <- as.data.frame(cov.mat)
  names(cov.mat) <- rep(paste0("X",1:30))
```

This dataframe has 30 columns (predictors).

Here's my logic of the loop:

1) Regress each predictor against other predictors and calculate R2. Convert R2 to VIF using VIF = 1/1 - R2. This will give me 30 VIF values.

2) Sort the VIF value. If the top predictor has VIF > 10, remove the predictor from the `cov.mat`. `cov.mat` will have 29 predictors now.

3) Repeat Step 1 i.e regress each predictor against other predictors and calculate VIF again (29 VIFs this time). If max VIF > 10, remove the variable with the highest VIF and keep doing till max VIF <= 10.

However, the catch is I want to keep X4 , X6 and X10 even if their VIF > 10 in a given iteration. So in the above process if X4 or X6 or X10 comes out to have the highest VIF (> 10) in an iteration, remove the variable with the second highest VIF (only if the second highest VIF is also > 10 and is not X4 or X6 or X10). I hope this is clear

```
  mat <- matrix(, ncol = 2, nrow = nrow(cov.mat)) #  this will store the 30 VIFs

for(i in 1:ncol(cov.mat)){
      mdl <- lm(cov.mat[,i] ~ ., data = cov.mat) # this will regress each column against other columns but throws an error when i = 2
      r.squared <- unlist(summary(mdl)[8]) # this gives the r-squared of predictor i
      vif <- 1/(1- r.squared^2) # calcualtion of VIF for predictor i
      mat[i,2]  <- vif
      mat[i,1]  <- names(cov.mat[i])
  }
```

Let's say the above loop works fine and I have a matrix with first column as variables names and second column with VIF values.

```
     df <- data.frame(mat)
     names(df) <- c("variable", "vif")
     df <- df[sort(df$vif),]

     ifelse(df[1,2] <= 10, stop, ifelse(df[1,2] > 10 & names(df[1,1]) != "X4" | names(df[1,1]) != "X6" | names(df[1,1]) != "X10", ....
```

This is where I am lost.

I first need to check if the variables with the highest VIF is > 10 and is not among X4 or x6 and X10, and remove the variable from dataframe `cov.mat`.
If the variable with highest VIF (given VIF > 10) is either X4 or X6 or X10, then go to the second row of `df` and evaluate whether its VIF > 10 or not and
whether it is not among X4, X6 or X10 and if it meets the condition, remove it from the `cov.mat` and start the iteration again.

**EDIT**

My original data frame has 51 columns and 1458 rows. When I run the above function, it gives me an error `there are aliased coefficients in the model`. 
Why is this happening?

Comment: There is something strange in your example. You probably want to calculate the VIFs for `rand.vars` while in your example the calculations are done on `cov.mat`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example data, the or VIF scores cannot be computed for the whole data set, most likely because of perfect colinearity. The function here should work however for data where that is not the case (columns 1:15 of your data set, for example). You can ignore/remove all the `cat` code. That was just to illustrate what is happening

Furthermore, I used the package `car` for the function `vif`

```
library(vif)

vif_fun <- function(df, keep_in) {
             # df: the dataset of interest
             # keep_in: the variables that should be kept in  
             highest <- c()
             while(TRUE) {
                # the rnorm() below is arbitrary as the VIF should not 
                # depend on it
                vifs <- vif(lm(rnorm(nrow(df)) ~. , data = df))
                adj_vifs <- vifs[-which(names(vifs) %in% keep_in)]
                if (max(adj_vifs) < 10) {
                     break
                }
               cat("\n")
               print(vifs)
               highest <- c(highest,names((which(adj_vifs == max(adj_vifs)))))
               cat("\n")
               cat("removed:", highest)
               cat("\n")
               df <- df[,-which(names(df) %in% highest)]

              }
            cat("\n")
            cat("final variables: \n")
            return(names(vifs))
              }

# example with mtcars dataset
vif_fun(mtcars,keep_in = c("cyl"))


# example using part of your data
vif_fun(cov.mat[,1:15], keep_in = c("X15", "X12"))
```

Comment: Thanks. This works for the sample data. However, when I run this for my data, it generates an error `there are aliased coefficients in the model`

Comment: this usually means that there is perfect collinearity among some of your variables, meaning that at least one variable can be expressed as a linear combination of the others. If that is the case, the VIF cannot be computed. Did you maybe plan to do the analysis with rand.vars instead of cov.mat?

Comment: `rand.vars` is just the made up data. My actual data is different but I understand your point now. Thank you